# pg_restore: error: could not read from input file (DBeaver for PostgreSQL in Oracle Virtual Machine), for .tar file

Tags: linux, postgresql, macos, dbeaver, pg-restore

Using DBeaver 21.0.3 with PostgreSQL13.2, on Oracle Virtual Machine on Oracle VirtualBox with Oracle linux7.9, in MacOS Catalina: (Did not install PgAdmin):

Trying to restore **dvdrental.tar** with following Restore Settings:

```
Format: custom
Backup File: /home/oracle/Downloads/dvdrental.tar
Extra command args:
Authentication:
Username: (given)
Password: (given)
save
local client: /usr/bin
Start
```

**Getting error**:

```
Warning: 
Database restore finished with warnings:
Please check the error log 
OK

/usr/bin/pg_restore --verbose --host=localhost --port=5432 --username= ... 
Task 'PostgreSQL restore' start at...
pg_restore: error: could not read from input file: end of file

Task 'PostgreSQL restore' finished:
PostgreSQL restore: 
Task [PostgreSQL rstore] is completed (62806ms)]
Object9s) processed: dvdrental
OK
```

Start

**Repeats the same error logs..**

Comment: Can we see the rest of the error message?

Comment: Hi Laurenz: Added complete error message.

Comment: Looks like `pg_restore` met an unexpected end of file. If you restore to a file with `pg_restore`, what does the end look like?